# Conditional expectation given an event and a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be an integrable real random variable on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$. If $A\in \mathcal A$ is an event with probability $0<P[A]<1$ then we have that

$$E[X|\sigma(A)]=1_A \frac{E[1_AX]}{P[A]}+1_{A^c} \frac{E[1_{A^c}X]}{P[A^c]} \quad P\text{-a.s.} $$

Now suppose $\mathcal F$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$. Am wondering if the following holds:

$$E[X|\sigma(A,\mathcal F)]=1_A \frac{E[1_AX|\mathcal F]}{P[A|\mathcal F]}+1_{A^c} \frac{E[1_{A^c}X|\mathcal F]}{P[A^c|\mathcal F]} \quad P\text{-a.s.} \quad \quad (1)$$

assuming that $0<P[A|\mathcal F]<1$ $P$-a.s. (I don't see how to dispense with this assumption).

It seems to me that the answer is  yes based on the following argument:

Let $Y$ denote the RHS of $(1)$.Then $Y$ is $\sigma(A,\mathcal F)$ measurable. We check that $Y$ is integrable using the conditional Jensen's inequality,the law of total expectation, and the pull-out property:

$$ E\Bigg[\Bigg|1_A \frac{E[1_AX|\mathcal F]}{P[A|\mathcal F]}\Bigg|\Bigg]\leq E\bigg[1_A \frac{E[1_A |X|\mid\mathcal F]}{P[A|\mathcal F]}\bigg]= E\bigg[E[1_A|\mathcal F] \frac{E[1_A |X|\mid\mathcal F]}{P[A|\mathcal F]}\bigg]=E[1_A|X|]< \infty$$

and similarly $E\Bigg[\Bigg|1_{A^c} \frac{E[1_{A^c}X|\mathcal F]}{P[A^c|\mathcal F]}\Bigg|\Bigg]<\infty$.

Now, we verify that $\sigma(A,\mathcal F)=\Big\{(A\cap B_1) \cup (A^c\cap B_2) : B_1,B_2\in\mathcal F \Big\}$, and therefore by additivity it is is sufficient to check that $E[1_{A\cap B}Y]=E[1_{A\cap B}X]$ and $E[1_{A^c\cap B}Y]=E[1_{A^c\cap B}X]$ for all $B\in\mathcal F$. This we verify by direct computation, using again the law of total expectation and the pull-out property:

$$E[1_{A\cap B}Y]=E\bigg[1_A\frac{E[1_{A\cap B}X|\mathcal F]}{P[A|\mathcal F]}\bigg]=E\bigg[E[1_A|\mathcal F]\frac{E[1_{A\cap B}X|\mathcal F]}{P[A|\mathcal F]}\bigg]=E[1_{A\cap B}X]$$

and similarly $E[1_{A^c\cap B}Y]=E[1_{A^c\cap B}X]$.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to ensure that $0<P[A|\mathcal F]<1$ $P$-a.s.?

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

**Proposition.** A necessary and sufficient condition for $0<P[A|\mathcal F]<1$ a.s. is that $P[A\cap B]>0$ and $P[A^c\cap B]>0$ for all $B\in \mathcal F$ with $P[B]>0$. In other words, the partition $\{A,A^c\}$ of $\Omega$ must split each non-null set of $\mathcal F$ into two non-null parts.

**Necessity.** Suppose $0<P[A|\mathcal F]<1$ a.s.. Let $B\in \mathcal F$ with $P[B]>0$. Then $$P[A\cap B]=E[1_{A\cap B}]=E[P[A|\mathcal F] 1_B]>0$$

for otherwise $P[A|\mathcal F] 1_B=0$ a.s. and so $P[A|\mathcal F]=0$ on an $\mathcal F$-measurable set of positive measure, contradiction. Similarly, $P[A^c\cap B]>0$, for otherwise  $P[A|\mathcal F]=1$ on an $\mathcal F$-measurable set of positive measure.

**Sufficiency.** Suppose $P[A\cap B]>0$ and $P[A^c\cap B]>0$ for all $B\in \mathcal F$ with $P[B]>0$.

Suppose first by contradiction that $P[A|\mathcal F]=0$ on a set $B\in \mathcal F$ with $P[B]>0$. Note that $P[B]<1$, for otherwise $P[A|\mathcal F]=0$ a.s. which implies $P[A]=0$, contradiction. Then

$$E[1_A|\mathcal F]=1_BE[1_A|\mathcal F]=E[1_{A\cap B}|\mathcal F]$$

and so $E[1_{A\cap B^c}|\mathcal F]=E[1_A|\mathcal F]-E[1_{A\cap B}|\mathcal F]=0$ a.s.. This implies $P[A\cap B^c]=0$, contrary to hypothesis.

Next suppose by contradiction that  $P[A|\mathcal F]=1$ on a set $B\in \mathcal F$ with $P[B]>0$. Note that $P[B]<1$, for otherwise $P[A|\mathcal F]=1$ a.s. which implies $P[A]=1$, contradiction. Then $E[1_A|\mathcal F]\geq 1_B$ a.s. and so

$$E[1_{A\cap B}|\mathcal F]=1_B E[1_A|\mathcal F]\geq 1_B=E[1_B|\mathcal F]$$

which implies $0\geq E[1_{A\cap B}-1_B|\mathcal F]\geq 0$ or $E[1_{A^c\cap B}|\mathcal F]=0$ a.s.. Hence $P[A^c\cap B]=0$, contrary to hypothesis.

Comment: You cannot prove that $0<P[A|\mathcal F] <1$ a.s. If $A \in \mathcal F$ then $P[A|\mathcal F]=I_A$ which takes only the values $0$ and $1$!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, so I have to assume $A\notin \mathcal F$ at least. But even in this case the assumption migh fail no?

Comment: There is no simple condition that ensures that $0<P[A|\mathcal F] <1$ a.s.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok so I will maintain it. Does the rest of my argument looks ok to you?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It may not be simple to check, but I think the following condition ensures $0<P[A|\mathcal F] <1$ a.s. : $P[A\cap B]>0$ and $P[A^c\cap B]>0$ for all $B\in \mathcal F$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I made an edit with the proof of the condition. What do you think?